# Coding assignment hiring process information

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Is there any interest or use in having recruiters provide the steps of their hiring process and/or code assignment requirements?

Beyond what they need code wise for the job, I find that I end up factoring how many interviews, and whether they either accept my existing code or want me to do a code assignment (and how long it is expected to take & complexity) into pursuing the job further, it could be beneficial to know this beforehand.

Comment: I dunno.  What difference would it make to you as an applicant if they did or didn't ask you to complete a coding assignment before you made it to the interview?  They *do* provide Joel Test scores, so you can see if they ask you to write any code at all before you bother with the application.

Comment: @Makoto : A few weeks ago I did 4 coding assignments, one was relatively simple ( fix some css ) the others were increasingly more complex, (one was a full app) and 3 pages of instructions, I think it is more efficient to know this before even applying. The process, how many interviews, with who etc, I think also could benefit finding the right culture & company to work for, again just an idea I am ok weeding out them myself :)

Comment: Each company has their own way of determining "fit", and doing a coding assignment is one of those ways.  It's not that I don't disagree - having done a few rounds of interviews myself, I've had at *least* 3 coding tests with varying degrees of difficulties across many languages.  Honestly though, why can't you ask these questions up front?  Don't make it sound like you don't want to do the assessments, but why not just...engage them before you get the ball rolling?  With Jobs, you have the opportunity to ask questions before you apply.

Comment: @Makoto: It's somehow complex, the coding assignment is in general a red flag for me, (  a poor measure of future performance/fit), applying at a job board is also time consuming task and to be honest a bit of a waste of time, but not a total one  ( see [SO developers survey](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/73-of-programmers-are-web-developers-and-other-insights-from-stack-overflows-massive-2017-survey-89a13b11e370)). There are though cases where I would gladly do a coding assignment if it is a) something fun and I have time or b) the company position is really cool, so it's about granularity.

Comment: @Keno I've had good experience with reviewing interviewees sample code. So far (out of maybe 4 new employees) it's been a great reflection of their output. I totally understand how it might feel like arbitrary and a waste of time on the applicants end, but having some actual code they wrote is a great indication of how they work.

Comment: @Keno totally understand you at least it will be useful to know how much time the recruitment process takes i.e. you'll have to sucess on 3 coding filters taking at most 2 hours each with one week interval between them.

Comment: @TankorSmash : That is survivorship bias, how about those 4 that you didn't hire because they didn't provide a code sample or had their own code base up for review ? <= read that in a maybe there is another, better way for some, I am not trying to pick up a fight with you and hope you and your company succeed : )

Comment: I just went through the hiring process recently - It seemed none of the employers wanted to look at the code I've written publicly on github (personal projects).  I didn't mind the few employers who asked for coding assignments though, because at least I knew they'd look at my code prior to hiring.  What really bothered me were the code tests in the interview.  I see no point to it and think interviews should be completely about clarifying questions about my code, soft-skills, and any other questions they have about *me*.  Technical reviews should be done prior to the interview.

Comment: @aaaaaa: I completely agree, I was recently asked a few lightning round gotcha questions, (How is a web page rendered, would you rather edit css or resize images for performance), I think this is yet another misguided metric, ( if performance is an issue to your company I will review your current state, inform myself on whatever is relevant and test in your specific implementation or something along those lines), also the feeling of surprise  ! you are in a game show now is horrible.

Comment: I've always just asked companies in the first interview what their process is like, or better yet, they'll volunteer that information. IMO, while it would be an interesting data point, it's really not a big deal to simply ask them if you're already interested enough to consider the company.

Comment: Being asked to write a full app during the interview process or generally do anything taking more than a day smells of exploiting the interview process to get free work done, or just going way overboard with the assessment. I wouldn't expect that to be common enough to justify any changes on the website (or maybe I've just been lucky to not have run into that).

Comment: @Keno I think you should also suggest button that immediately posts coding assignment from jobs to SO. This will save applicants even more time - no need to even read the assignment :) In reality "I wrote this code" has almost no weight unless you actually observe person's coding style in person. So asking real coding questions is essentially must for most cases and easier to apply uniformly to all...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Microsoft where you work is known for whiteboard and multiple coding tests plus multiple hourly interviews, it is far from a settled matter whether [this type of hiring is the best](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/tech-hiring-has-always-been-broken-heres-how-i-survived-it-for-decades-b7ac33088de6), your opinion is valuable, but once again how would you know ? Have you done an A/B on your hiring process vs another one ? Coding style might be important for your team, but not for another one, these issues could benefit from metrics.